# php pdo switching primary key values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am sorry if this has been asked but I can't find anything that can help me. I am trying to switch the values of two primary keys in my table as in 1 becomes 2 and 2 becomes 1 .
I am receiving this error 
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY

I am not very familiar with mysql. How would you solve this problem

```
<?php
//Connect to the DB
require_once('connect.php');
//insert names into the DB
$MoveToTwo = '2';
$MoveToOne = '1';

try{
    global $db;
    $inserts = $db->prepare("UPDATE slider_images SET id=:MoveToOne WHERE id=:MoveToTwo");
    $inserts = $db->prepare("UPDATE slider_images SET id=:MoveToTwo WHERE id=:MoveToOne");
    $inserts->bindParam(':MoveToOne', $MoveToOne);
    $inserts->bindParam(':MoveToTwo', $MoveToTwo);
    $inserts->execute();
}

catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Prepare one query ... execute it... prepare the second query... then execute that query

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your problem, you do this to sort your row.

In mysql manipulate a the id is a bad idea because it is the mysql identifier for your row and is automatically generated.

A better solution it's to add a new column named like ordered (do not use order because is Mysql key reserved). Then you can update more easily this value without conflict and in your select query add `ORDER BY ordered ASC` to have the same effect as before.

To complete your save, you need to add a value on row creation. For that you do count on your ROW number before saving your entry.

Comment: thank you very much for your help I will create a new column.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` column of your table is set as a primary key, which **must** be unique and thus cannot be updated to an already existing value. The only option would be to delete the row and reinsert it with the new value.

There is however a problem with your code, you are preparing twice and the second time you are overwriting your first prepare. Secondly, the whole point of prepared statements is that you can re-bind values.

```
$dstmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM slider_images WHERE id = ?");
$sstmt = $db->prepare("SELECT cola, colb, colc, etc FROM slider_images  WHERE id = ?");
$istmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO slider_images (id, colb, colc, etc) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

$result_a = $sstmt->execute([$MoveToOne]);
$result_b = $sstmt->execute([$MoveToTwo]);

$row_a = $result_a->fetch();
$row_b = $result_b->fetch();

$dstmt->execute([$MoveToTwo]);
$dstmt->execute([$MoveToOne]);

$istmt->execute([$MoveToOne, $row_b['colb'], $row_b['colc'], $row_b['etc']]);
$istmt->execute([$MoveToTwo, $row_a['colb'], $row_a['colc'], $row_a['etc']]);
```

Its a lot shorter like this and essentially does the same, however you can use the update statement if you are sure that id does not exist.

Comment: Took some edits, but now it should work as expected.